# Hide Axis in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

How can I hide both x and y axis in a bokeh plot ?
I've checked and tried based on this :

```
p1= figure (... visible=None)
p1.select({"type": "Axis", "visible": 0})
xaxis = Axis(plot=p1, visible = 0)
```

and like
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#axes

Comment: Got it !         plot.axis.visible = None

Answer (score 75):

Create a figure object.
So, in your example the figure object is `p1`,
then `p1.axis.visible = False`
If you want to specify a y or x axis, then use
`p1.xaxis.visible = False`
or `p1.yaxis.visible = False`

Answer (score -3):

Set the axes parameters in the figure object:

`p1 <- figure(xaxes = FALSE, yaxes = FALSE)`

or if you also want to hide the grid lines:

`p1 <- figure(xgrid = FALSE, ygrid = FALSE, xaxes = FALSE, yaxes = FALSE)`

Details are here:
https://hafen.github.io/rbokeh/rd.html#ly_segments

Comment: probably confusion, but OP was talking about Python.